# Dji fpv will not link in digital fpv mode

Tags: first-person-view, video-transmitters, troubleshooting, dji

I bought the DJI fpv kit and I am trying to change the VTX from 25mW to 700mW. I don’t see a setting in the goggles until I change it to digital fpv mode. But when I do that, I can see the setting in device but it’s grayed out and the drone is not linked to the goggles, ie: No video or any info is shown. What am I doing wrong? I am in the USA. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

John